All image textures are black or transparent
I was opening up a model I was working on a while ago, and all the image textures are gone.
the main texture and emissive mask is all black, and the transparency mask is all transparent.
does anyone know how I could recover these or no?


Is it still the same after restarting Blender? I just had the same problem. It was the first time this happened. The shaders were apparently not compiled correctly and everything was just black. Restarting Blender fixed it.

yup I tries restarting blender, also tried it after restarting my computer too and it didn't help.

Does the problem only occur with this blend file or does it always happen? I don't know if this will help, but you can create a new file and append the collections to it (File > Append ...), which will copy the models to the new file. Hopefully, they will no longer be black there.

just tried it and it's still turning black, I looked at the image textures themselves too and they're all just black... I think the image textures are just screwed :(((
also yeah it was just this blend file. I think something just screwed up and made all the textures black

Oh, that's bad, sorry :( You know that you have to save painted images individually, don't you? They are not saved with the blend file.
